# The attributes of a user made object won't print (C++)

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to make an object with a series of user inputs but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code:
(No Errors occur)

Making the class and using a constructor function so if it wasn't user made it would be easier to enter details:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Person{
    public:
    string FirstName;
    string Surname;
    string Gender;
    int Age;
    double Money;
    Person(string aFirstName, string aSurname, string aGender, int aAge, double aMoney){
        aFirstName = FirstName;
        aSurname = Surname;
        aGender = Gender;
        aAge = Age;
        aMoney = Money;
        }
                
    };
```

Declaring the variables that will be substituted in later and getting them with a user input:

```
int main(){
        string bFirstName;
        string bSurname;
        string bGender;
        int bAge;
        double bMoney;
        cout << "What is your character's First Name?" <<endl;
        getline(cin, bFirstName);
        cout << "What is your character's Surname?" <<endl;
        getline(cin, bSurname);
        cout << "What is your character's Gender?" <<endl;
        getline(cin, bGender);
        cout << "What is your character's Age?" <<endl;
        cin >> bAge;
        cout << "How much money does your character have?" <<endl;
        cin >> bMoney;

        // Then substituting the variables into an object:

        Person Custom1(bFirstName, bSurname, bGender, bAge, bMoney);

        // And finally trying to print the gender out 
        // (I have tried all the other as well with no success) 
        // and ending the program:

        cout << Custom1.Gender;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your constructor. You're not assigning the arguments to the members, you've swapped it around.

Comment: You have the item you are assigning reversed. Note the the variable you are assigning to should be on the left not right.

Comment: You might also consider the use ctor initializer list when assigning the values, like  `ctor(int t_v) : m_v(t_v) {}`

Comment: I am a little surprised you did not get a warning about `Age` and `Money`. With the assignment backwards you are making use of uninitialized member variables to overwrite the passed in parameters. There are warnings here: [https://wandbox.org/permlink/jpOt0YGwxZWnQnx6](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jpOt0YGwxZWnQnx6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor has the initializations the wrong way around. Try this:

```
Person(string aFirstName, string aSurname, string aGender, int aAge, double aMoney){
        FirstName = aFirstName;
        Surname = aSurname;
        Gender = aGender;
        Age = aAge;
        Money = aMoney;
        }
```

Comment: It's generally preferable to phrase the answer as a statement rather than a question.

Comment: After the question, is the statement.

Comment: Ok, but why is there a question at all?

Comment: You may want to show member wise initialization in addition to this.

Comment: @cigien It was just me thinking out loud... I'll fix it.  Thanks, cigien.

Comment: The asker can also take advantage of the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). It's often faster (directly initializes an object rather than default construction and assignment later) and the compiler will emit errors if you get the logic backward.

Comment: Actually, that sentence was fine, it just should have been an assertion. I've edited to make it clear what I meant. Without that sentence, it becomes a code only answer, which is also not ideal. Is the edit ok?